# Getting Additional Data from SOAP response

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am receiving the below SOAP response from a web service.

```
<soap:Body>
<SubscriptionQueryResponse>
    <Subscriptions>
        <Subscription></Subscription>
        <Subscription></Subscription>
    </Subscriptions>
    <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
    <ResultCount>2</ResultCount>
    <StartingSequence>0</StartingSequence>
</SubscriptionQueryResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I need to get the Total Count.

Below is my code:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod( "&&&", RequestElementName = "SubscriptionQueryRequest", RequestNamespace = "&&&", ResponseNamespace = "&&&", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped )]
    [return: XmlArray("Subscriptions")]
    [return: XmlArrayItem("Subscription", IsNullable = false)]
    public Subscription[] SubscriptionQuery(string SubscriberId, int SortType, bool SortDescending, string Service, string ReferenceID, string SubscriptionName, int StartingSequence, int ResultCount )
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke( "SubscriptionQuery", new object[] {
                SubscriberId, 
                SortType, 
                SortDescending,
                Service,
                ReferenceID,
                SubscriptionName, 
                StartingSequence,
                ResultCount
        } );
        return ( (Subscription[])( results[0] ) );
    }
```

As you can see, I am already returning the subscriptions.  The list of subscriptions is in index 0 of the returned array.  I would like to also return Total Count as index 1 of the returned array but the return XmlArray statements only return the subscriptions and cast them automatically.

EDIT: At minimum, I would like the raw XML without it serializing it and I can parse it myself.

NOTE: ignore the "&&&" in the SoapDocumentMethod.  I removed their values for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to not have the framework serialize the xml.

```
[SoapDocumentMethod( "&&&", RequestElementName = "SubscriptionQueryRequest", RequestNamespace = "&&&", ResponseNamespace = "&&&", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped )]
[return: XmlAnyElement]
public List<XmlNode> SubscriptionQuery(string SubscriberId, int SortType, bool SortDescending, string Service, string ReferenceID, string SubscriptionName, int StartingSequence, int ResultCount )
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke( "SubscriptionQuery", new object[] {
            SubscriberId, 
            SortType, 
            SortDescending,
            Service,
            ReferenceID,
            SubscriptionName, 
            StartingSequence,
            ResultCount
    } );
    return ( (List<XmlNode>)( results[0] ) );
}
```

This cast all the nodes in the response into a list, and then I could take each individual node that I wanted in the response and de-serialize them myself instead of having the framework do it.